# In keras based LSTM, Is it ok feature size of input shape is smaller than the data size?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

If the shape of my training set is `[Sample=1, timestep=6, features=6]`,
if we put (`Sample=1, timestep=6, features=1`) in batch input shape on keras,
will the remaining features be ignored or repeated until the sixth feature? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is not clear. For example, if your input data has dimension of input tensor is (100, 6, 6) you need to specify the input_shape of LSTM to match the input data shape as `LSTM(32, input_shape=(6, 6))`

Comment: Thanks comments. I already know that. However, in keras, it works even when LSTM(32, batch_input_shape=(6, 1)), so I am curious about how it works.

Comment: I surprise if it works, if the LSTM is the first layer in your model and input_shape of LSTM does not match with the shape of input data, it throws an error. Can you include the code for the entire model